# Log4j2: Handle new day

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j2

I'm working on an application that requires multiple services running, so I want to create a folder for every day that will contain the different services' logs, here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_LEVEL">INFO</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%-5p %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] [%c{1}] (%F:%L) - %m %n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="${LOG_LEVEL}" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <!-- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingRandomAccessFileAppender -->
        <!-- Async Loggers will auto-flush in batches, so switch off immediateFlush. -->
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="File"
                                 fileName="${sys:serviceLogDir}/${date:yyyyMMdd}/${sys:serviceLogFilePrefix}-${date:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.log"
                                 filePattern="${sys:serviceLogDir}/$${date:yyyyMMdd}/${sys:serviceLogFilePrefix}-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip"
                                 immediateFlush="false"
                                 append="true">

            <ThresholdFilter level="${LOG_LEVEL}" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>

            <!-- DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/ -->

        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${LOG_LEVEL}" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

This code works fine if I stop my services every day, here's an example:

[image: Log4j2 folders]

You can see in the screen shot the folders created for each day and the log files inside.
Now the issue is when I don't stop my services and I keep them running until the day after, the folder for the next day doesn't get created and the log files of yesterday keep being updated in yesterday's folder, what I want is for logs to stop at midnight, create a new folder for the new day and create new logs for the new day (or move yesterday's logs to the new folder).

Thanks.